# SQL Inner Joins inside Outer Joins; Nesting Alters Results

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I'm a bit surprised that these two queries give different results:

First Query:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name , b.*
FROM Atable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Btable b
JOIN Ctable c ON c.number = b.number
ON b.number = a.number
ORDER BY a.number;
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name , b.*
FROM Atable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Btable b ON b.number = a.number
JOIN Ctable c ON c.number = b.number
ORDER BY a.number
```

My expectation is that both of these would return the results that the first query does. The first query returns every row from TableA; however, unexpectedly, the second row only returns results from TableA if they also exist in TableC.

Why does the join from C to B restrict TableA in the second query but not in the first query?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the same as why (A + B)*C is different from A + (B*C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query, with parens to clarify how it is parsed:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name , b.*
FROM Atable a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (Btable b JOIN
      Ctable c
      ON c.number = b.number
     ) ON b.number = a.number
ORDER BY a.number;
```

Having two `on` clauses in a row is confusing, so the parentheses help.  This makes it clear that you are keeping all rows from the first table.

The second query is:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name , b.*
FROM (Atable a LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Btable b
      ON b.number = a.number
     ) JOIN
     Ctable c
     ON c.number = b.number
ORDER BY a.number;
```

You are inner joining the result of the first join.  Hence, only rows that match will go to the result set.

When you are doing multiple joins, I recommend using `left join` for all the joins.  Mixing inner and outer joins can lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. Your placement of the parentheses helps it to make sense. After doing some research on query processing order, it's clicking much better. Appreciate it!